# 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to make a cash register, but when I do the tax, I want to have it with two decimal places, instead of something like $3.006743

I tried to do this:

```
elif item == 'done':
    os.system('cls')
    tprice = sprice * 1.13
    hst = tprice - sprice
    if tprice >= 1:
        tprice = tprice[0:5]
    elif tprice >= 10:
        tprice = tprice[0:6]
    elif tprice >= 100:
        tprice = tprice[0:7]
    if hst >= 1:
        hst = hst[0:5]
    elif hst >= 10:
        hst = hst[0:6]
    elif hst >= 100:
        hst = hst[0:7]
    print(receipt)
```

But I get the error. Any help?

Comment: You can't use bracket notation `[]` on `float`s.  You need to make them strings if you want that syntax to be valid.  `str(tprice)`.

Comment: `tprice` is a float, you cannot index it like that. You just want to round it when printing?

Comment: Just use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), rather than trying to hard-code rounding or whatever it is you're hoping to do with those subscripts. e.g. `'{0:.2f}'.format(hst)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(3.123456) 
'3.12'
>>> '$ {:.2f}'.format(12.999)
'$ 13.00'
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(.029)
'0.03'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this for currencies I would also recommend looking at [python limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/python-limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points), because rounding floats will cause your calculations to be incorrect. Many people store cents (in an integer) and divide by 100, or use python's [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) type.